# Приостановка работы метода

Tags: c#, таймер

Есть некий фабричный метод, возвращающий объект *X* по вызову. Сам объект *X*, который формируется по запросу, принимает входные параметры, и в конструкторе запускает метод `method`, после завершения работы которого объект *X* будет возвращен.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы формируемый объект *X* "строился" заданное количество времени (например 20 секунд).

Можно реализовать это посредством `thread.sleep`. Однако выглядеть это будет не очень корректно. Также возможно сделать таймер и цикл `while(flag)`, где флаг станет `false` после *timer tick*.  Однако хотелось бы добиться необходимой работы только посредством использования таймера.  Однако при такой архитектуре, при запуске таймера и подписке на него, работа метода `method` (который запускается из конструктора и настраивает объект *X*) будет завершена сразу же, и никакого ожидания не будет.

Решится ли вопрос, если запускать метод не из конструктора, а после создания объекта?

Как лучше всего реализовать приостановку работы определенного метода?

Comment: А почему `Thread.Sleep` некорректно? У вас есть какие-то дополнительные требования, которые вы не озвучиваете?

Comment: Если выполнение `method` действительно занимает 20 секунд, то почему бы просто не выполнить его синхронно? Или у вас откуда-то приходят данные в другом потоке? Ваша проблема выглядит странно, наверное, вы что-то недорассказываете.

Comment: Потому что в рамках заданного времени(20 секунд) происходит подписка на события, которые обрабатываются в одном потоке. А Thread.sleep усыпит этот поток. Данные приходят в этом же потоке и важно работать с ними 20 секунд.

Comment: Непонятно. Как данные могут приходить в поток, который находится в синхронном вызове фабричного метода? Так не выйдет. Может быть, async/await?

Comment: В объекте X, который строится фабрикой, есть  подключение к источникам данных, которое обернуто в простые методы объекта "resource". Объект resource прокидывается через фабричный метод и передается Объекту X. Методы объекта resource  и используются для подключения.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда почему нужно ждать? И _чего_ именно? Почему нельзя просто синхронно вызвать нужные методы объекта `resource`?

Comment: у обьекта resource есть набор событий, подписка на которые происходит в обьекте  X.  Так вот подписка и работа с подключением должна длиться ровно 20 секунд

Comment: таковы требования. Данные, которые приходят - динамические и важно получать их в строго определенный интервал- 20 сек

Comment: Окей, начинает проясняться. Давайте я расскажу ваш случай, а вы объясните, так это или нет. Объект _X_ при инициализации должен опросить источники данных. Для этого он подписывается на сообщения от источников данных, и инициирует какой-то процесс на этих источниках. Когда ответы ото всех источников придут, объект готов к использованию, и может быть возвращён пользователю. Правильно?

Comment: Не со всем так, ответа от источников может и не быть. Есть некий процесс, который отдает всем приемникам(подписчикам) набор данных. Данные эти могут меняться постоянно. Условия задачи таковы, что 1 итерация опроса - 20 секунд и для расчета необходимо "слушать" источники через объект resource в объекте X(1 объект X = 1 итерация = 20 сек). Это задача связана не с простой инициализацией подключений, а именно с работой с данными в течение заданного промежутка времени.

Comment: Собрали мы данные или не собрали в течение 20 секунд - никакого значения не имеет и зависит только от наличия этих данных. Не собрали - будет одна логика работы, собрали - другая.

Comment: Окей, понятно. Теперь важный вопрос: в каком потоке приходят сообщения от источников данных? В том, в котором запрашивается объект, или в другом? Это **очень** важно.

Comment: Данные приходят в том же потоке, в котором запрашивается объект X. Объект X должен "слушать" их 20 сек., после чего он будет возвращен с теми данными, которые он собрал или не собрал.

Comment: Это почти невозможно. Каким образом приходят данные? Если это event'ы, каким образом они будут отправлены, если данный поток занят конструированием объекта? Код, посылающий event'ы, просто не получит управление во время блокирующего вызова.

Comment: Покажите код, принимающий данные (и отправляющий). Что-то тут не так.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я имел не совсем то, о чем был вопрос. Данные приходят в другом потоке, это естественно. Мы просто можем подписаться на их получение в объекте X через событие объекта resource, который работает с данными.

Comment: Тогда вполне можно обойтись `Thread.Sleep`. За это время event'ы придут в другом потоке, и объект будет инициализирован. Ну или если вы не хотите блокировать поток на 20 секунд, вам нужен async/await. Ваш поток, в котором происходит создание объекта — это UI-поток?

Comment: Нет, конечно это не UI поток. Я пытаюсь понять, насколько такое архитектурное решение, требующее использования Thread.Sleep, является оптимальным.

Comment: С моей точки зрения, `Thread.Sleep` неоправданно блокирует поток на долгое время, поэтому я бы перешёл на async/await и заменил его на `await Task.Delay(...)`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Предлагаю Вам оформить последний комментарий в виде ответа, чтобы нам закрыть эту раздувшуюся беседу.

Comment: Угу, так и сделал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С моей точки зрения, `Thread.Sleep` неоправданно блокирует поток на долгое время, поэтому я бы перешёл на async/await и заменил его на `await Task.Delay(...)`.

Впрочем, для фонового потока это может быть не принципиально.

Поскольку объект при инициализации получает данные из другого потока, не забудьте о правильной синхронизации!

Comment: "для фонового потока это может быть не принципиально" -- но может быть важно для приложения и системы в целом.

Comment: @andreycha: это да, поэтому лишь «может быть».

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел еще одно решение проблемы. указанной в вопросе. Мне кажется, что самым эффективным способом заданного ожидания в работе метода является использование связки таймера и EventWaitHandle. Запускаем работу нашего метода в новом потоке и ждем(WaitOne) пока произойдет событие. А событие произойдет, когда отработает таймер(Set произойдет в обработчике таймера). Ссылка: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Приатачить отладчик и запустить Debugger.Break() и отладчик заберет управление на себя. ;-)